# Render template on iframe by template ID

Tags: joomla-3.x, templates

I am facing a problem with the rendering template after duplicating. The situation is I want to load a template on iFrame. So, I've set the URL of the iFrame like-

```
Uri::root(true) . '/index.php?template=my_template'
```

This is working fine. But the problem is I need to duplicate the template (as many as I want) and after duplicating the URL `Uri::root(true) . '/index.php?template=my_template'` renders the template which encountered first in the database.

For example, If my original template id is `9` at `#__template_styles` table and I make a duplicate copy of the template and the id is `10` then the URL `Uri::root(true) . '/index.php?template=my_template'` always renders the template which id is `9`.

So, the question is - *Is there any way to render the template with it's ID (in this case with ID 10)?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `templateStyle` query parameter.

```
index.php?templateStyle=9
```

This only works on site application (same is true for `template` parameter).

Comment: can you help on it? https://joomla.stackexchange.com/questions/28595/joomla-apply-sef-route-from-templates-index-php-file @sharky