# Joomla apply SEF route from template's index.php file

Tags: templates, sef, redirect

I am having a problem recently is that- I am creating a Joomla Site Template and for a specific condition, the template redirects to `http://mydomain.com/index.php?templateStyle=10&tmpl=custom`.

Now I want to convert this `?templateStyle=10&tmpl=cutom` to a SEF url like `/10-template-name/custom`.

Is there any way to do such from the templates `index.php` file?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no.
Only the menu and components can define sef routes. The other option is to run something early in the life cycle to mess with the routing directly, but the template runs much too late for that. A system plugin would be the extension for this.